# Get query param before being redirected in Angular 14

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, parameter-passing, url-parameters

in my Angular app I want to show the user a certain message once he clicks on a link sent him by email.
The link will open a page, on the app, on this URL: `"localhost:8080/?dog="NiceDog!"`
The problem is that if I try to access the URL above, my routing will redirect the user to the home page: `localhost:8080/home/insert`

(A piece of the routing)

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is getting the query param and its value BEFORE being redirected by my own routing, is this even possible? Thanks

Comment: Are you using redirect for the `''` path in the routes?

Comment: Yep, it will take me to "/home/insert"

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to get the queryParams from your current url, also you can learn more  about Router States and URL Matching :https://indepth.dev/posts/1024/the-three-pillars-of-the-angular-router-router-states-and-url-matching

```
this.paramMap = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams;
```